# Type constraints about generics that a generic type argument uses

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to define an interface `IScheduler` that takes an `T1` and returns a `T2`, and also has a type argument for an `IJob<T1,T2>` so that it knows what job to create. I'd like to call it as so:

```
public class SomeJob : IJob<string, int>

// preferred way to use the method
int result = scheduler.Schedule<SomeJob>("some_param");
```

and have the compiler infer that `T1` is a string and `T2` is an int. This is how I've tried defining the interface

```
public interface IScheduler
{
    T2 Schedule<TJob, T1, T2>(T1 args) where TJob: IJob<T1, T2>;
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler complains:

```
Using the generic method 'Schedule<TJob,T1,T2>(T1)' requires 3 type arguments

The type 'SomeJob' must be convertible to 'Job<T1, T2>' in order to use it as parameter 'TJob` in the generic method 'T2 IScheduler.Schedule<TJob,T1,T2>(T1)'
```

What I'd really like to do is this:

```
public interface IScheduler
{
    T2 Schedule<TJob>(T1 args) where TJob: IJob<T1, T2>;
}
```

Comment: You can't, you must supply all generic arguments when calling `Schedule`.

Comment: there are two problems. first is that you cant define generic arguments partially. so when you write `<SomeJob>` you must define all. compiler doesn't support partially defining generic arguments in any case. second problem is that compiler can not infer the type `int` because `int result` is just the local variable. what would happen if you just call `scheduler.Schedule` and not storing the result anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't quite possible to get the syntax that you're looking for, but here are some things that would work:

```
int result = scheduler.Schedule(new SomeJob(), "some_param");

// using this
public interface IScheduler
{
    T2 Schedule<T1, T2>(IJob<T1, T2> job, T1 args);
}
```

Or:

```
int result = scheduler.ForJob<SomeJob>.Schedule("some_param");

// using this
public interface IScheduler
{
    IJobScheduler<TJob> ForJob<TJob>();
}
public interface IJobScheduler<out TJob> { }

public static class Extensions 
{
    public static T2 Schedule<T1, T2>(this IJobScheduler<IJob<T1, T2>> job, T1 args)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or if you can get rid of the return argument, you can access the strongly typed type of `TJob` in the `Schedule` method:

```
scheduler.ForJob<JobWithNoReturn>().Schedule("some_param");

// using the stuff from #2 and also this
public static class Extensions 
{
    ...

    public static void Schedule<TJob, T1>(this IJobScheduler<TJob> job, T1 args)
        where TJob : IJob<T1>
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't both of these cause `SomeJob` to have to support any `T1` or `T2`? Versus constraining them to `string` and `int`?

Comment: @Guvante: `T1` and `T2` in both of these cases will be based on the definition of `SomeJob`. Supposing it only implements `IJob<string, int>`, then `T1` and `T2` will be treated as `string` and `int`.

Comment: Hmm, interesting extension method magic. So you don't have to constrain `ForJob<TJob>();` to only take `IJob<>`s because you only define an extension method when they do pass in an `IJob<>`. I think in my case I will call both `IScheduler`.